Can VSCode show the full contents of a list instead of collapsing it at intervals of 25
I'm working with a list that contains 1000 objects. To avoid loading them into the UI all at once, the debugger in VSCode has a [More] dropdown at intervals of 25, with each [More] being nested under the last.
Theoretically, to see the latter end of my list, each time I run the debugger I would have to click [More] 40 times, and would have to chase it down and to the right of the viewport as I go in order to keep up with the nesting. This has made it very cumbersome to debug my code.
Is there a setting that changes this so that VSCode will load in the full list all at once, or at least a reasonable portion of it like 100 or 250 entries instead of just 25?


Wouldn't it be better to add a Watch variable that only shows the last N items?

I agree pana. I rarely have a need to view 1000 items at once, but instead a specific one or at least a specific set of some 10s or so. If you have found these once, add a watch for it and have it available for fast search.

You can use compile time directives and add additional objects you want to view while debugging, and not during release builds.  For example, a second collection that is only a subset of the last 10 entries.  Then you don't have to set up a new watch each time you restart the debugger.
